# Scale object vertex groups by proximity to other object using geometry nodes

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes, vertex-groups

What I want to achieve in my scene: A dolphin is moving towards an object (the sphere in this case).

The Distance to the sphere should determine the scale of the Dolphin but not by just uniformly scaling the dolphin. Rather the sphere should influence the scale of the vertex group by proximity so that for example the dolphin is scaled down on his nose tip where he is closer or inside the object and what's behind him is still the normal size.

Does this make sense? I want a smooth transition within the dolphin's mesh. It should scale at a certain point tied to the sphere so the Dolphin is fully scaled down on the side that's closer to the object but normal size where its more distanced.

I've already tried to create a node tree (see picture) but I am really not an expert. The dolphin uniformly scales by proximity but it doesn't consider the vertex group I created (it includes the full mesh of the dolphin). See blend file below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify? Scale about which point? Do you want the dolphin to scale along its own normals? Towards its nose? Away from the surface of the sphere? Can you describe/sketch out the end-effect?

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure about the effect you want to achieve, but if you want this:

[image]

you can do it with this node setup:

[image]

Comment: haha, funny, I came to the same conclusion and thought, that looks so much better anyway :D ...but I'm afraid that's not the solution (which I also could not find)

Comment: @quellenform I have no direct solution now and no time to figure it out - but Chris and you might be better with GN anyway - just my idea, maybe you can make something out of it: with the _Set Position_ node there must be a way if you plug something in the _Offset_ input... like _Distance_ between _Position_ (of the dolphin's vertices) and _Location_ (of the sphere), set to negative values by multiplying or _Map Range_, scaling the original _Position_ values.

Comment: i personally think a lattice modifier would be the much better way....but my dolphin doesn't shrink in length...i have no idea why‍♂️[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/80DUe.gif

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Good idea! I also tried this with `Set Position`, but the result is unfortunately unusable. The problem here is more this individual situation, because no matter how the vectors are scaled/offset, it always looks stupid. And my opinion is: If it doesn't look good, it's wrong :D

Comment: @Chris ...hm, yes, with *Lattice Modifier* it looks much better ;-)

Comment: i think the problem is that set position won't work because if you scale down the elements (which they do on their own center point), you don't have an "easy formula" to move them as one piece together again...

Comment: thx for all the suggestions!! seems like its harder than I thought, I will try all of these things :) and don't worry @quellenform , its a dolphin getting gradually stretched/scaled, that might look stupid quickly haha

Comment: @benji_kickflip: what did you do with your dolphin, that i can't even scale it right in edit mode? it scales absolutely weird....

Comment: @Chris just downloaded it from sketch fab and prolonged it... had to decimate the mesh quite a lot to get the blend file under 30mb